# Error Installing PySCIPOpt on Mac OSX

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, scip

After installing SCIP Optimization Suite on OS X by compiling the source and installing Cython,

```
make
make install INSTALLDIR="/usr/local/"
make SHARED=true GMP=false READLINE=false scipoptlib
pip install Cython
```

the installation of `PySCIPOpt` was attempted

```
git clone https://github.com/SCIP-Interfaces/PySCIPOpt.git
cd PySCIPOpt
$ SCIPOPTDIR=./ python setup.py install
```

But this gave an error. Any suggestions?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "setup.py", line 29, in <module>
scipsrcdir = sorted(scipsrcdir)[-1]  # use the latest version
IndexError: list index out of range
```

---

### Problem importing library

After successfully installing `pyscipopt`, when the library is being imported using

```
from pyscipopt.scip import Model
```

I get the `Library not loaded` error

```
  File "test.py", line 1, in <module>
    from pyscipopt import Model
  File "/Users/test/anaconda/envs/test/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyscipopt/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from pyscipopt.scip      import Model
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/test/anaconda/envs/test/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyscipopt/scip.so, 2): Library not loaded: lib/libscipopt-3.2.1.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt.so
  Referenced from: /Users/test/anaconda/envs/test/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyscipopt/scip.so
  Reason: image not found
```

After some searching, I tried someone's solution:

```
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path/to/scipoptsuite-3.2.1/lib
```

but running the Python file again gives a different error `Symbol not found: _history_length`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 1, in <module>
    from pyscipopt import Model
  File "/Users/test/anaconda/envs/test/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyscipopt/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from pyscipopt.scip      import Model
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/test/anaconda/envs/test/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyscipopt/scip.so, 2): Symbol not found: _history_length
  Referenced from: /Users/test/Desktop/scipoptsuite-3.2.1/lib/libscipopt-3.2.1.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt.so
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /Users/test/Desktop/scipoptsuite-3.2.1/lib/libscipopt-3.2.1.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt.so
```

Comment: _history_length sounds like the readline dependency of SCIP. Maybe just rebuild the SCIP optsuite with READLINE=false, as readline shouldn't be necessary for the Python interface anyway.

Comment: @stefan I rebuild it with `make SHARED=true GMP=false READLINE=false scipoptlib`, but it is still giving the same errors

Comment: @Nyxynyx you might try to run `otool -L` on the `scip.so` library that was generated and is throwing the error. This way you should be able to see undefined references to other libraries.

Comment: Had the same issue and exporting DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH= ... Helped me.

Answer (score 0):

When you set the SCIPOPTDIR environment variable, it looks for directories of the form ${SCIPOPTDIR}/scip-*/src.

You get that error because you do not have any directories that match that form in a freshly cloned checkout of PySCIPopt.git. You need to set that environment variable to the directory where you installed the "SCIP Optimization Suite".

Comment: Thanks, I managed to install but encountered problems when importing the library in the Python script... Updated question with details

Answer (score 0):

You need to have SCIP installed first. The shared library of the SCIP Optimization Suite to be precise. The environment variable SCIPOPTDIR must then be set to its root directory - not the directory of the Python interface. Please follow the instructions in the INSTALL file carefully: https://github.com/SCIP-Interfaces/PySCIPOpt/blob/master/INSTALL.md

Comment: Thanks, I managed to install but encountered problems when importing the library in the Python script... Updated question with details